# Javascript date increase by a year and subtract a day

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a date from a vuetify date picker. I take that date and I am trying to format it to MM/DD/YYYY however I need to first add a year to it then subtract one day. So January 1 2022 will become December 31 2022. My code is as follows:

```
            formatDateNextYear(date) {
                if (!date) return null

                let a = new Date(date);

                a.setDate(a.getDate() - 1)
                a.setFullYear(a.getFullYear+1)

                const [year, month, day] = a.split('-')
                return `${month}/${day}/${year}`
            }
```

My issue is this does not seem to add the year and is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `getFullYear`, and instead of trying to format it yourself, you can use `toLocaleDateString` and pass in the locale you want the format to be in:

```js
function formatDateNextYear(date) {
    if (!date) return null;

    let a = new Date(date);

    a.setDate(a.getDate() - 1);
    a.setFullYear(a.getFullYear() + 1);

    return a.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
}

console.log(formatDateNextYear(new Date("01/01/2022")));
```

Comment: Strange when I plug this into my vue app and run it and choose say 7/01/2022 with the date picker it returns 6/29/2023 using the function rather than 6/30/2023.

Comment: @IrishRedneck That *is* strange since inputting `7/01/2022` to this function works as expected. You might need to show your Vue code.

Comment: Oh i check and Date shows on my screen as 6-29-2022 EST time and that makes the date for end date 6-29-2023 EST. I need to somehow convert to UTC for both then return in MM/DD/YYYY.